# Which side of the bag holds each Tefilla?

Tags: tefilin

Over on https://torah.org/learning/mishna-berura-s28/ paragraph MB7, the MB discusses on which side of the tefillin bag each tefilla is placed.

My question is, in what orientation is the bag held when the text is considered.  Zipper up or zipper toward the user (which means that the embroidered name is upside down.)

Can anyone clarify?

Comment: Sorry, but I cannot see what the problem is, can you clarify what you are looking for?

Comment: I doubt the MB had ever seen a zipper

Comment: I believe what is important is to know where they are placed so you can get the arm tefilin out first without passing over the shel rosh. I find it easiest to put the shel yad on the side where the zipper first opens

Comment: Why would it matter which way it's oriented?

Comment: On re-reading MB 28.2 comment 7, paraphrasing) the important thing is the give the Shel Rosh a bit extra honor. Do not take out the Shel Rosh before the Shel Yad since you will apply the Shel Yad first. Shulchan Shlomo says that it is "proper" to put the Shel Yad on the right, but then the paragraph goes off into issues of two separate bags and making a mark on one of them so you know. I am starting to think that my question doesn't matter as long as the user makes a choice of how he is considering the bag.  @DoubleAA  My grandfather's tefillin bag had a button to hold it closed.